# keyPressed() method not working after mousePressed()

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, mouselistener, mousemotionlistener

I am trying to make a GUI program that switches states when mouse is clicked and moves a BufferedImage when the corresponding keys are pressed. But when the states are switched the keyPressed() method of keyListener is not being invoked.I added keyListener, mouseListener and mousesMotionListener to the JFrame and the JFrame is also set to focusable but it is still not being invoked. To be more specific the states are just objects of a state class with different methods inside.

Comment: *But when the states are switched the keyPressed() method of keyListener is not being invoked* - a KeyEvent is only generate for the component with focus. Some component other that the frame has focus. Don't use a KeyListener. Instead, Swing was designed to be used with `Key Bindings` which can handle events even if the component doesn't have focus. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information.

Comment: @camickr I am not trying to move a JComponent but am trying to move a BufferedImage which is being drawn in the canvas by using the draw method of graphics. So, is it possible to change the co-ordinates of the image using Key Bindings?

Comment: It doesn't matter what you are trying to do with the Key Bindings. All your code does is respond to an event. Instead of the code being defined in the KeyListener, the code is defined in the `Action`. So you can do anything when the event is generated. See [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for a complete working example